# How to ignore files from 'git status' if only white spaces and line breaks changed

Tags: git

I often push code with some tab instead of spaces or vice versa, or insert a line break to improve code readability. How do I tell git not to look for those changes?

Comment: shame this was never answered. I am switching between linux and windows and a bunch of files which have not really changed are showing up with `git status`. Would be nice to see with git status what really changed before committing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git diff -w | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

Patch would be applied with add without white space changes.

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question. I simply want to ignore files in "git status". I don't care about patches at this point.

Comment: how to set git globaly to ignore whitespaces!

Comment: I get the error "error: unrecognized input" when I run this from Git Bash on Windows.

Answer (score 16):

I could not find a native git solution for identifying what *really* changed using `git status` but the following one-liner works well under linux:

```
for m in $(git status | grep modified| awk '{print $2}');do test -z "$(git diff -w $m)" || echo $m;done
```

The result will be a list of modified files excluding files with only whitespace changes.

This is especially useful before writing commit messages when you want to see only the files with real edits which is often a problem when moving back and forth between windows and linux systems. If you have control of both systems then configuring whitespace settings in git may be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I needed to change the {print $2} to a {print $3}. but a very good solution. Possibly a different git version perhaps?

Comment: Nice! Works in cygwin, too.

Comment: You can also do `git ls-files -m` rather than `git status | grep modified | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to find non-white changes in your workspace, `git diff` really is your friend (as apposed to "git status"). git diff has a couple of options to tailor this, some of which are

```
--ignore-space-at-eol
--ignore-space-change / -b
--ignore-all-space / -w
```

If you are interested in a git status-like list of changed files, you can issue

```
git diff --name-only
```

Unfortunately, combining that with e.g. `-w` to see only files that contain non-white changes does not work (at least not in my current version of git, 2.15)

So what I came up with to achieve the latter, is to use the normal git diff -w command and then extract the file names:

```
git diff -w |grep "^--- a"
```

This is taking advantage of the way git diff introduces the output of differences of a specific file, and is a tad simpler than other one-line scripts people suggested on this page.

One caveat: AFAIK inserting a line break *in the middle of text* (e.g. to improve code readability, as the OP describes) will never be ignored, as it is effectively replacing one line of text with two new lines.