# Removing unnecessary changes in git working directory

Tags: git, github

Each time I want to make `git pull`, or `git push`, I have a lot of changes not staged for commit when I use `git status` (modified files). These contain added spaces, tabs, etc, so changes that I don't want to push to git, but also don't want to have them in `git status`. I'd like to remove them, so revert the changes so that it looks like it's in the repo.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore files from 'git status' if only white spaces and line breaks changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467836/how-to-ignore-files-from-git-status-if-only-white-spaces-and-line-breaks-chang)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19467836/1407656

Comment: The possibly stupid way I do it is `git stash` and then `git stash pop` when I'm done. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash (The stupid part is "forgetting to `stash pop` and then realizing I have a `git stash` and no bloody clue what I was doing.)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen save your stashes with a message - `git stash save "I was doing foobar"`. Also, see what they look like with `git diff stash@{0}`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do a `git checkout *` and that reverts everything back to what's in repo.

Answer (score 0):

For each file that you want to revert, run:

```
git checkout -- <filename>
```